# jQuery loading images on demand

Tags: jquery, image, download

I am trying to load images on demand, in order to prevent downloading of unneeded images. I am  using jQuery. So far, this is what I have come up with:

```
$('#region_image').attr({'src':'/images/'+e.key+'.jpg'}).load(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
// e.key is the name of the image I want to load now.
```

Are there any caveats to using this?

**EDIT:**

*Caveat Nr. 1:*

When binding the load event in a loop, remember it will be bound twice on the next run.

*Caveat Nr. 2:*

The image attempted to load must, at all times, exist, or error handling should be in place.

Comment: You should probably use ".prop()" instead of ".attr()" if you're using a jQuery version newer than 1.5.x.

Comment: Here is an interesting CSS-based technique to do the same - load images on demand. http://podlipensky.com/2013/06/css-only-load-images-on-demand/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good library: [JAIL](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL)

Selected images will be downloaded if they are visible and when they are visible inside the viewport (rectangular viewing region). Images can be loaded after an event is triggered (such as click, mouseover, and scroll) or after a specified delay. It's advisable to call jail() after the DOM has been constructed (document ready).