# jQuery - How to stop image loading unless requested

Tags: jquery, image, load

Is it possible to stop images from loading, until requested via jQuery?

I'm currently using jQuery Waypoints, and would like to only load images in to the document once at that certain location...

This goes for images in an IMG tag, and also Background Images?

Comment: This might be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464786/jquery-loading-images-on-demand

Comment: You could look for some lazy load jquery plugin.

Comment: search for lazy load +1 because I want to go to heaven

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse I did think about doing that (Without the plugin) such as using a data-image attribute then when Waypoints gets to that place, it loads the image from the data-image in to the src attribute. 

But I didn't know if that was a bit messy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time an `<img>` tag is created, or an `Image` object has its `.src` property set, it'll start trying to load.

The only way that I know to do what you want is to ensure that the element isn't created until it's actually needed.

If you know how big the images are, you could use a 1x1 place holder scaled up to the right size, and then replace the place holder's `.src` with the correct image when you need it.  That should at least keep your page layout stable and avoid reflows.

Comment: what about background image applied via css?

Comment: @JosiahRuddell same there - you'd have to dynamically apply the style when it's needed, rather than have it in your static CSS Files.

Comment: @Alnitak Do you mean by having something like a 'data-image' attribute, then get jQuery to request that file from the attribute and place it in to 'src' once the page has loaded?

I thought about that, but I didn't know if it was a bit messy. Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: @JasonMayo There is no other way.

Comment: @JasonMayo yeah, that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create images without any tags, so browser will have nothing to load. And then force browser to load the images when needed. Checkout this tutorial of [how to load images on demand](http://podlipensky.com/2013/06/css-only-load-images-on-demand/)