# When does the browser load images into the working memory?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a image-intensive web-page. I just popped in all the images and the site got really slow. Not just loading but also browsing etc.

Is there any good way to tell a browser that images are not necessary to load yet? For example in css:

```
display:none
```

or maybe instantiating the images with javascript somehow.

Currently all images are specified in the html, if possible I would like to keep to like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464786/jquery-loading-images-on-demand

Comment: I disagree, I don't even use jquery.

Comment: there is a jquery plugin [lazy load](http://www.appelsiini.net/2007/9/lazy-load-images-jquery-plugin)

Comment: you don't want ANY plugin??

Comment: I want to use what ever is needed. I quess my question really is when does the browser load images in to the working-memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="myID" src="about:blank" alt="" />

document.getElementById("myID").src="/image1.jpg";
```

I have to admit though, I have not used a blank image tag before, but If needed I have always appended an image to a container dynamically

```
document.getElementById("myDivID").appendChild('<img id="myID" src="image1.jpg" alt="" />');
```